# Azure Functions not able to access partition context in eventhub trigger in Java

Tags: java, function, azure

I am trying to access the **partition context from EventHubTrigger Azure Functions** using **Java** language but not able to get it.It's throwing error in the run time. Please help me.

CODE

```
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventData;
import com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.BindingName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.Cardinality;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.EventHubTrigger;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
public class Eventhubtriggerfn {


    @FunctionName("Eventhubtriggerfn")
    public void run(
        @BindingName("SystemProperties") Map<String, Object> systemProperties,
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "message", eventHubName = "deveventhub", connection = "AzureEventHubConnection", 
        consumerGroup = "$Default", cardinality = Cardinality.ONE) EventData events,PartitionContext partitionContext,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
}
```

ERROR

```
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM] Executed 'Functions.Eventhubtriggerfn' (Failed, Id=ed76248e-8d1b-46ec-98fa-ddf9ba300c18)
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.Eventhubtriggerfn. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: UnsupportedOperationException: Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventData
Stack: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventData. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM]         at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:228)
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM]         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM]         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM]         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM]         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
[9/14/2019 11:48:34 AM]         at
```

Thanks in advance